# OS Heap and OS stack in an multicore OS

Tags: operating-system, x86, arm, multicore

I am writing a small smp kernel and now I am adding support for the second core.
Here are a few questions that are cropping up

a) I believe each core would have its own stack and that has the be defined in lds file

b) I believe each core would have its own heap (for malloc) and that has the be defined in lds file

c) common data structures should go in bss section

d) For per cpu variables a _per_cpu_area for each core to be set in lds file and a register say r0 would always point to  per cpu section

e) locks across cores to be help in bss section

Are these assumptions correct ?
Please verify or raise any problem

Answer (score 1):

```
Functions have stacks,
Processes have heaps,
   where they all shared by those nasty threads...
Only zero initialized data goes into BSS,
   and you should see Linux's per_cpu...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a preemptive multitasker:

> a) I believe each core would have its own stack and that has the be
>   defined in lds file

Cores don't have stacks, they have stack pointers that get swapped aroung on thread context-changes.  Threads have stacks.

> b) I believe each core would have its own heap (for malloc) and that
>   has the be defined in lds file

Cores don't have heaps.  Processes have heaps.

> c) common data structures should go in bss section

Maybe, depends if read-only.

> d) For per cpu variables a _per_cpu_area for each core to be set in
>   lds file and a register say r0 would always point to per cpu section

CPU's don't generally have variables, unless you mean hardware registers, which it appears you do not.

> e) locks across cores to be help in bss section

Cores don't have bss sections.  Applications have bss sections. Vars in bss may need locks if multiple threads can access them, no matter whether one core or more.

You need to Google/read more about OS operation - you have some things rather confused.

Comment: Further to Martin James's last comment: Go and buy the book that made Linus Torvolds so unhappy: Modern Operating Systems by Andrew Tannenbaum - where a lot of this theory is explained.